# relation "users_user" does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

so I am trying to migrate my app after just creating a project and this error just pop up out of the blue.. **LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "users_user" WHERE "users_user"."user...**. the only thing I did differently was that I used abstract user to extend my user models so that I can be able to give my user a specific role. It also does not allow me to create a super user as it throws the same error. I am new to all of this so some help can be really useful currently using Django 4.04. I tried deleting all migrations files and rerun migrations and didn't change anything

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField('Admin', default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField('Teacher', default=False)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard/'

LOGIN_URL = 'login/'
```

**form.py**

```
from attr import field
from django import forms
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class TeacherRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()


    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ["username", 'email', 'password1', 'password2']


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_teacher = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Can you show me the error message?

Comment: it seems like i needed to delete my database to fix the problem

Comment: So, now is it okay?

Comment: Extending the user model at any time other than immediately after starting the project can cause issues - I'm guessing this was your problem, and that's why removing the database and recreating it fixed the issue.

Comment: @DavidLu and michjnich yes it was fix now next time i will do it from the start